# Regular expression: return matched word up to the the next full stop

Tags: regex

I wanted to return the key word and everything proceeding it until it reaches the first possible full stop. For example if the sentences were

```
The house was full of tables and chairs. He did not like them.
```

If the key word were house, I'd like to return

```
house was full of tables and chairs.
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? But anyway... `house[^.]*\.`

Comment: Thanks, @ctwheels. (I confess I haven't tried anything, I'm about to leave work and needed something asap!)

Comment: What a horrible usage of StackOverflow!

Comment: @0605002 A question is good use of SO, lots of other people may have the same question, even if I hadn't tried anything yet :-)

Comment: Will you accept some answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
house[^\.]+\.
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/QmR1xE/2)

Comment: Not me, but I think that's because you ignored part of the question about key word,

Comment: As @Qwertiy mentioned, it doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: Thanks :-) I didn't know about that website.

Comment: Well, +1 from me anyway.

Comment: Now it does answer it

Comment: @marvel308 I've removed my downvote. Also, escaping the dot inside brackets is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

```js
var text = "The house was full of tables and chairs. He did not like them."
var match = text.match(/house[^.]*\./)
var res = match && match[0]
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I wrote in the comment?

Comment: @ctwheels and? a correct answer is better than a correct comment

Comment: @ctwheels, I was answering and haven't seen you comment. I's not strange that 2 people found the same nice solution.

Comment: @ctwheels, but we both made a mistake - last dot have to be escaped.

Comment: Completely agree, in any case it's not like I downvoted this as it is correct.

Comment: @ctwheels, currently there is no downwotes :)